# Playing games in ubuntu

Tags: 13.04

Is there any chance anyone played Cricket 2007 in ubuntu? I use 13.04 and any idea how to do it if it is possible? It does not work with wine. Any other software that does not want me to pay?

Answer (score 0):

You can play the game using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).  But according to the [Wine program Database](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=18320), the game was tested on Ubuntu 12.04, and everything works.

It hasn't been tested with 13.04.